# Commenting a "block" on a line-by-line basis

Tags: xml, comments

*(Background)* Many languages have two comment syntaxes. For example in C# or C++ you can do:

```
/*void Method(int arg)
{
  Validate(arg);
  Log.Add("Validated");
  DoWork(arg);
}*/
```

or:

```
//void Method(int arg)
//{
//  Validate(arg);
//  Log.Add("Validated");
//  DoWork(arg);
//}
```

Many people prefer the latter because it is more clear that every line is commented out. *(end of Background)*

---

Now, in XML you have only one (quite poor) way of commenting stuff. But in can still be used in different ways.

Suppose I have this XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Zootheque>
  <Animal Name="Elephant">
    <Descrption>Is really huge and has a long and flexible nose.</Descrption>
    <NumberOfLegs>4</NumberOfLegs>
  </Animal>
  <Animal Name="Snake">
    <Descrption>Will make you (Eve) eat forbidden fruit.</Descrption>
    <NumberOfLegs>0</NumberOfLegs>
  </Animal>
  <Animal Name="Ostrich">
    <Descrption>You cannot see it if its head is buried in sand.</Descrption>
    <NumberOfLegs>2</NumberOfLegs>
  </Animal>
</Zootheque>
```

Suppose I want to comment out the element about `Snake`. In Microsoft Visual Studio and some simple text editors, when I select the relevant "block" of lines and choose *Comment out the selected lines* or similar, I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Zootheque>
  <Animal Name="Elephant">
    <Descrption>Is really huge and has a long and flexible nose.</Descrption>
    <NumberOfLegs>4</NumberOfLegs>
  </Animal>
  <!--<Animal Name="Snake">
    <Descrption>Will make you (Eve) eat forbidden fruit.</Descrption>
    <NumberOfLegs>0</NumberOfLegs>
  </Animal>-->
  <Animal Name="Ostrich">
    <Descrption>You cannot see it if its head is buried in sand.</Descrption>
    <NumberOfLegs>2</NumberOfLegs>
  </Animal>
</Zootheque>
```

I feel that the above comment style is sometimes problematic. Instead I want:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Zootheque>
  <Animal Name="Elephant">
    <Descrption>Is really huge and has a long and flexible nose.</Descrption>
    <NumberOfLegs>4</NumberOfLegs>
  </Animal>
  <!--<Animal Name="Snake">-->
  <!--  <Descrption>Will make you (Eve) eat forbidden fruit.</Descrption>-->
  <!--  <NumberOfLegs>0</NumberOfLegs>-->
  <!--</Animal>-->
  <Animal Name="Ostrich">
    <Descrption>You cannot see it if its head is buried in sand.</Descrption>
    <NumberOfLegs>2</NumberOfLegs>
  </Animal>
</Zootheque>
```

**Question 1:** Does the latter commenting style for XML have a name? (Which would help if I needed to google this.)

**Question 2:** Is creation of that kind of comments, with a single keystroke or mouseclick (after lines have been selected), supported in Visual Studio? Or supported in some other (XML) text editor you can recommend?

---

**LATER ADDITION:** I just discovered that (a sufficiently new version of) [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) has this feature. You select multiple lines and use *Single line comment* (Ctrl+K) or *Toggle single line comment* (Ctrl+Q).

Answer (score 0):

I think the answers to (1) and (2) are "no" and "no", but it's hard to prove non-existence.

It's true that the inability to nest comments is a design weakness (XML tried to be compatible with SGML, and compatibility means deliberately repeating other people's mistakes, as David Wheeler used to say.) Various XML editors I have used have various attempts to solve the problem, but none of them is perfect.

Comment: As a consequence of the second no, one may want to write a macro/plugin/extension that does what I request. I still think it is strange if no-one has the same preference as I have (commenting line-by-line even if you need to "ignore" an entire "block"), given that line-by-line comments are normal in other languages I have encountered. Until other answers appear, we can call this the Nielsen comment style ;-)